# Mongo bi shut down when sampling MongoDB for schema,How to debug and find the reason?

Tags: mongodb

the mongosqld.log show me that mongobi is shutting down

> 2021-10-15T10:04:11.538+0800 I NETWORK    [initandlisten] waiting for
> connections at [::]:3307 2021-10-15T10:04:11.538+0800 I NETWORK
> [initandlisten] waiting for connections at /tmp/mysql.sock
> 2021-10-15T10:04:11.547+0800 I SCHEMA     [sampler] sampling MongoDB
> for schema... 2021-10-15T10:04:17.949+0800 I CONTROL
> [signalProcessingThread] shutting down
> But I coundnt find why,what should i do to find the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue there is `signalProcessingThread` - something sent the process a signal like SIGTERM.

Comment: Thanks, I found that my mongobi work actually well but my docker container which my mongobi in will be closed by some other reason so that my mongobi log tell me it is closed.